# spacy_install on R, the error occurs: Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve

Tags: r, spacy

I'm trying to use spacyr in R. So I ran the below code.

```
spacy_install()
```

Then, what R returned was below. How can I make R ready to do the next step, which is spacy_initialization()?

```
> spacy_install()
Proceed? 

1: No
2: Yes

Selection: 2
Using existing conda environment  spacy_condaenv  for spaCy installation
. 
spaCy and language model(s): en_core_web_sm will be installed.  Installing spaCy...
+ "C:/Users/Ryo/miniconda3/condabin/conda.bat" "install" "--yes" "--name" "spacy_condaenv" "-c" "conda-forge" "spacy"
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: ...working... failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
```

OS: Windows 10
RStudio: 4.3.2.